# Multiple Parent Category URLs

Tags: categories, permalinks, taxonomy, urls

I've inherited a mess of a Wordpress site and I'm hoping someone can offer a solution without using custom post-types & custom taxonomies.

Example of my issue, I have the following categories set up:

```
topic1
topic2
topic3
news
guides
```

None of them are child/sub categories. Now my posts are set with both a topic category and a news/guides category

```
e.g.
topic1 + news
topic2 + news
topic1 + guides
```

I need a page that shows all of the posts with the categories 'topic1' AND 'news' and ideally the url should use both categories

```
e.g. //mysite.com/topic1/news
```

Does anyone know if this is this possible at all without resorting to using custom post-types, custom taxonomies, or additional tags?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Matt

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to do any of that.

When you set up a category in the backend of a WordPress website, the archive is normally created/taken care of for you. So if you create a category called 'Massive Dogs' and you got to "/massive-dogs' after you have created a post in that category (and the slug is the same), you should see  your post item.

The URL would only reflect that if you had parent/child categories.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-categories-and-subcategories-to-wordpress/

Anything beyond that would likely need you to create some custom functionality in the function file and/or create some custom templates.

It would be interesting to know why you would need that kind of URL structure. Surely anything in `'topic1/news'` would just be news?

I hope this helps but if not, comment and I'll be happy to help further :)

Comment: Downvote with no explanation?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply (the downvote wasn't me by the way) however I'm afraid this only partially answers my question in as much as you say:

**Anything beyond that would likely need you to create some custom functionality in the function file and/or create some custom templates.**

I know how Wordpress taxonomy works and the setup I've inherited does as I expect it too. It's just that a post in a particular topic may be either a 'news' item or a 'guide' item. I don't want to create child 'news' & 'guide' categories for each topic though.

Comment: Which suggests I'll likely either have to live with what I've got, or have to create custom post types (which I don't really want to do as there's a lot of posts already)